# Facebook - Tagging Friends via Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook just published this post:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/07/building-better-stories-with-location-and-friends/

Explaining that applications can now tag users and locations in posts! This is great news, but I am getting an error when I try. Here is my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => '***',
    'secret'    => '***',
));

$page_id = "245694995445225";
$args = array(
    'access_token'  => '***',
    'message'   => 'Tagging Friend',
    'place'     => '189766701075056',
    'tags'      => '100002490263808',
);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```

And this is the error that I receive:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Cannot create the tag thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fbtest/sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1106
```

If I remove the "tags" parameter, it posts fine with the location. Any ideas why "tags" isn't working yet?

Comment: I just tested this with a profile, and it works. Any chance it will work with pages soon?

Answer (score 0):

below code worked for me

```
             $params=array();       

             $params['message'] = "Hi Friends ";
             $params['tags']=$frends; //comma separated friends ID's
             $params['place']='155021662189'; 

             $params['name'] = "Some namee";
             $params['link'] = "http://blaha.com";
             $params['description'] = "blah blah blah blah";
             $params['picture'] = "image link"; 
             $params['caption'] = "Join ";


            $shared=$facebook->api("/".$user['id']."/feed", "post", $params);
                         or 
                    $shared=$facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $params);
```

Answer (score -2):

You must specify tags first, then place.

```
$args = array(
  'access_token'  => '***',
  'message'   => 'Tagging Friend',
  'tags'      => '100002490263808',
  'place'     => '189766701075056'
);
```

I think it will work.